# Optional id for default action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got a site with only this Route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Image", action = "Image", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Image(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            // Do something
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is the default action so i can access it without an ID just by directly going to my domain. For calling the id it works just fine by going to /Image/Image/ID. However what i want is calling this without Image/Image (so /ID). This doesn't work now.

Is this a limitation of the default Route or is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new route specific for this url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Image Details",
    url: "Image/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "Image" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });
```

Make sure you register the above route before this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Otherwise it will not work, since the default route will take precedence.

Here I'm stating that if the url contains "/Image/1" then the `ImageController/Image` action method is executed.

`public ActionResult Image(int id) { //..... // }`

The constraint means that the {id} parameter must be a number (based on the regular expression `\d+`), so there's no need for a nullable int, unless you do want a nullable int, in that case remove the constraint.

Comment: And register this route *before* the existing `controller/action/id` route!

Comment: Recommend updating your answer with this :)

Comment: Thanks this got me in the right direction. I ended up using this Route.             
            routes.MapRoute("Image Details", "{id}",
                new {controller = "Image", action = "Image"}
                );

I removed the Image/ from Image/{id}. The contraint wasn't needed either.

Comment: @Fortitude the constraint is strongly recommended, and could even be required. Otherwise a request to something like `/Home` will end up matching the new image-only route, instead of matching `controller=Home`.